# Backup document directory on iCloud without sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

How can I actually backup my app document directory by using iCloud, so that user can switch over iCloud accounts and get his app data, related to that particular account.
    And my document directory contains sqlite database file and images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read the `iOS Data Storage Guidelines`,

> To ensure that backups are as efficient as possible, store your app’s data according to the following guidelines:
>
> 1. Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the `Application_Home/Documents` directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.
> 2. Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the `Application_Home/Library/Caches` directory. Examples of files
>      you should put in the Caches directory include database cache files
>      and downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper,
>      and map applications.
> 3. Data that is used only temporarily should be stored in the `Application_Home/tmp` directory. Although these files are not backed
>      up to iCloud, remember to delete those files when you are done with
>      them so that they do not continue to consume space on the user’s
>      device.
> 4. Use the "`do not back up`" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute
>      with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low
>      storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because
>      customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute
>      works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in,
>      including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and
>      will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because
>      these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible
>      for monitoring and purging these files periodically.

As per guidelines, `Application_Home/Documents` will be automatically backed up by iCloud.

**References and useful links**

1. https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/BestPractices/BestPractices.html
3. https://developer.apple.com/icloud/

Comment: thanx for ur reply, but it is not working. And also my app name is not appearing in the 'Manage Storage', instead it appears under 'iCloud Drive'.